# PHP Email utf8 not accepted

Tags: php, email, utf-8

I am having a problem with sending emails with PHP. When i send an email it looks like he does not accept utf-8 this is what i get :

> &auml ;ccount

When i use a var_dump on the variable it just says  äccount, so in the mail is something going wrong.

Here is the code i use for the headers :

```
  $headers = 'From: ' . $send_from. "\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

Thanks in forehand for the help :)

Comment: Do you create the body of the email itself as properly formatted HTML or as plain text?

Comment: I created as properly formatted HTML

Comment: Is that space before the semicolon really there in the output, or is that a copy/paste mistake?

Comment: I just noticed it now, its a copy/paste mistake

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a space between the `&auml` and the `;`. Remove it and your HTML should display correctly.